# How does one determine what the left and right context IDs should be when building a MeCab 0.996 user dictionary with UniDic 2.3.0?

Tags: ubuntu, cjk, mecab

I'm trying to build a [MeCab 0.996](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/) user dictionary with [UniDic CWJ 2.3.0](https://unidic.ninjal.ac.jp/download) on Ubuntu 20.10 using the following terminal command:

```
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u ~/foo/bar/foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/foo.csv
```

where foo.csv is:

```
ダイバーシティ,,,-200,名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ-diversity,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,外,*,*,*,*,*,*,体,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,,,,,
```

But I get this error:

```
dictionary.cpp(355) [cid->left_size() == matrix.left_size() && cid->right_size() == matrix.right_size()] Context ID files(/usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/left-id.def or /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/right-id.def may be broken
```

This unresolved GitHub issue post seems to be related but goes over my head: https://github.com/taku910/mecab/issues/42

I'm able to build a MeCab user dictionary with the older [unidic-mecab-2.1.2](https://unidic.ninjal.ac.jp/back_number#unidic_bccwj):

```
$ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d ~/mecab/unidic-mecab-2.1.2_src/ -u ~/foo/bar/foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/foo.csv
./pos-id.def is not found. minimum setting is used
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
done!
```

I'm also able to build a user dictionary using the reiwa.33.csv from the [unidic-py documentation](https://github.com/polm/unidic-py/tree/master/extras):

```
/usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0 -u ~/foo/bar/reiwa33.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/reiwa.33.csv
/usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/pos-id.def is not found. minimum setting is used
reading /home/foo/bar/reiwa.33.csv ... 3
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
done!
```

The reiwa.33.csv is:

```
令和,4786,4786,8205,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,令和,レーワ,令和,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
㋿,5969,5969,2588,補助記号,一般,*,*,*,*,,㋿,㋿,,㋿,,記号,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,,,*,*,*,*,999999
㋿,4786,4786,3992,名詞,固有名詞,一般,*,*,*,レイワ,令和,㋿,レーワ,㋿,レーワ,固,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,レイワ,"1,0",*,*,*,*
```

Thus, the difference between the two csv files is that the left and right context IDs are specified for each surface form (and the aType and lemma_id for some but not all entries) in the reiwa.33.csv, but not in the foo.csv.

According to the [instructions](https://taku910.github.io/mecab/dic.html) for MeCab, mecab-dict-index will automatically assign the left and right IDs,and that seems to be the case with unidic-mecab-2.1.2, but not for UniDic 2.3.0.

So, I guess the question becomes: How does one determine what the left and right context IDs should be? Is there an explanation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer in [this Qiita post](https://qiita.com/awakia/items/9a0dec41d91c997c74b4).

To determine the left and right context IDs:

1. View the left-id.def and right-id.def files respectively:

```
    $ gedit /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/left-id.def

    $ gedit /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/right-id.def
```

2. Find the line which matches the features of the word.

   For general foreign loanword nouns (e.g., ダイバーシティ) without a
   specified accent type (aType) or accent change type (aConType) the
   values are:

```
    left-id: 15917 名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,*,外,*,*,*,*,*,*

    right-id: 17160 名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,*,外,*,*,*,*,*,*
```

3. Thus foo.csv should be:

```
    ダイバーシティ,15917,17160,-200,名詞,普通名詞,一般,*,*,*,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ-diversity,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,外,*,*,*,*,*,*,体,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,ダイバーシティ,*,*,*,*,*
```

4. Compiling the MeCab dictionary with UniDic CWJ 2.3.0 from foo.csv then works without the "left- or right-id.def may be broken error":

```
    $ /usr/local/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index -d /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/ -u ~/foo/bar/foo.dic -f utf8 -t utf8 ~/foo/bar/foo.csv
    /usr/local/lib/unidic/unidic-cwj-2.3.0/pos-id.def is not found. minimum setting is used
    reading /home/foo/bar/foo.csv ... 1
    emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
    done!
```

Note: The values in the reiwa.33.csv appear to be for UniDic 2.1.2.

For a detailed explanation of why the left/right-id.def error occurs and how to swap all the left and right values in matrix.def, see [this Japanese Stack Overflow post](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/74219/44059).

Comment: Hello, glad you figured out something that gets it to work. You should be able to leave the context IDs blank in theory... They should only be used if training with HMMs if I recall correctly, which means in practice they're never used at all.

Comment: Thanks! I tried leaving them blank at first, but that doesn't seem to fly with UniDic 2.3.0

Comment: @polm23 According to the explanation on [this page](http://www.mwsoft.jp/programming/munou/mecab_nitteretou.html), the left and right context IDs are used when parsing text. Is the author incorrect?

Comment: To update what I said here: I was wrong and the context IDs are used. I was mis-remembering a statement by the MeCab designer about them being unecessary from a design perspective.